# Typing interfaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

What is the correct way to type an "interface" in python 3?

In the following sample:

```
class One(object):
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 42


class Two(object):
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 142


def factory(a: str):
    if a == "one":
        return One()

    return Two()
```

what would be the correct way to type the return value of the `factory` function?

It should be something like "A type with a single method named `foo` that accepts no arguments and returns an integer".

But not sure I can find how to do that.

**UPD**: this question is **exclusively dedicated** to typing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a `typing.Union` but, it sounds like you really want *structural typing* not nominal. [Python supports this using `typing.Protocol`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/), which is a supported part of the python type-hinting system, so `mypy` will understand it, for example:

```
import typing

class Fooable(typing.Protocol):
    def foo(self) -> int:
        ...

class One(object):
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 42


class Two(object):
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 142


def factory(a: str) -> Fooable:
    if a == "one":
        return One()

    return Two()

x = factory('one')
x.foo()
```

Note, structural typing fits well with Python's duck-typing ethos. Python's typing system supports both structural and nominal forms.

Comment: Just to mention from my own deleted answer, `typing.Protocol` is only available starting in Python 3.8. Versions 3.6 and 3.7 can import `Protocol` from [`typing_extensions`](https://github.com/python/typing/tree/master/typing_extensions).

Comment: Oh, that's so cool. I will accept a bit later and award bounty when it allows to (the cooldown period is 24hrs)

Answer (score -4):

The `->` doesn't really do much in python.

```
>>> def foo()->int:
...     return "yeet"
...
>>> foo()
'yeet'
```

Similarly with denoting types in method signatures:

```
>>> def bar(a: int):
...     print(a)
...
>>> bar("yeet")
'yeet'
```

The syntax is really just a means of commenting your code. Conceptually you could implement something of an interface by raising an exception in the constructor.

```
>>> class foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...             raise()
...     def someFunc(self):
...             return(42)
...
>>> class bar(foo):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.whatEver = "idk"
...
>>> a = bar()
>>> a.someFunc()
42
>>> baz = foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

However you will not get the benefits of type stringency that you are looking for because python isn't a <s>strongly typed</s> language. `Edit: Python doesn't use static typing.`

Comment: a) Python is a strongly typed language. It doesn't use *static* typing, but "strongly" typed isn't synonymous with static typing. It doesn't support static type checking, although the third-party library `mypy` does b) this doesn't really answer the question, which is how to correctly type-annotate that function

Comment: This is completely missing the point of the question. The OP is using type hinting, static type checking *with an external tool*. Type hints can express what the OP wants perfectly, as juanpa’s answer shows.